# Automatically add a new node to a drop-down menu

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

When a user creates a node of a certain type, I want that node to be added to a drop-down menu at the top of the screen: i.e., so that when the user mouseovers the parent item in that menu, a list of all the nodes of that type is displayed. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this effect by using https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus, and building a view that contains all of the nodes I want displayed in the drop-down. Then https://drupal.org/project/menu_views can display that view as menu items within the menu that Nice Menus has built.